# Can you pack these pentacubes to form a rectangular block with at least one odd side length other the side whose length must be a multiple of 5

Tags: mathematics, geometry, three-dimensional, packing

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #11: Now in 3D](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7475/monthly-topic-challenge-11-now-in-3d).</sub>

---

Consider the following pentacube (made from 5 unit cubes):

[image: Pentacube with base 1x2x2 block with one unit cube above the base]

It is possible to pack four of these pentacubes to form a 2x2x5 rectangular block. And from that packing it is possible to pack any rectangular block whose three side lengths are 2i, 2j and 5k where i, j and k are arbitrary positive integers.

By volume considerations, for any packing of a rectangular block with these pentacubes, there must be a side length that is a multiple of 5.  But is it possible that one or both of the other side lengths is an odd number?  For example, is it possible to pack a 5x5x5 cube with these pentacubes?

Comment: I'm having trouble even visualizing the 2x2x5, lol, it's not that trivial I guess. (I got it alrd now from the first answer)

Comment: If you add the [tag:three-dimensional] tag and edit in the template header this could be a last-ditch entry for this month's [MTC](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7475/monthly-topic-challenge-11-now-in-3d)...

Comment: On [Torsten Sillke's site](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~sillke/results.html) there are lots of results for polycube packings including a page with [results for this pentacube](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Esillke/PENTA/qu5.61).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, for instance we can make a 2x7x15 block.

Put together two pentacubes to make a P pentomino two layers deep:
[image]

Then, arrange 21 P pentominoes in 2D to make the 7x15 rectangle below.

[image]

*Image from https://polyominoes.org/data/5P*

Comment: I like this solution because it solves a 3-dimensional puzzle using a 2-dimensional technique.

Comment: @Bass’ edit makes @xnor’s answer even better because it shows how the 2 level P pentomino is constructed.  Also when you tap/click on the pentomino diagram you get a larger version of it (great for people with reduced vision).

Answer (score 13):

5x5x5 block:

> is impossible: Consider the 27 gold cubelets in the following image:
> [image: 5x5x5 with all cubes with only odd coordinates marked]
> Each pentacube can only cover 1 of these cubelets, so you need at least 27 pentacubes. However, those 27 pentacubes will have 135 cubelets in total, and there are only 125 cubelets of space in the 5x5x5 cube.

Comment: Great use of minecraft

Answer (score 10):

Here is a small one with sides of 2x3x5:

> [image]

However, I don't believe that a 5x5x5 is possible. I do not have a proof, but the fact that it is mostly 2x2, which is hard to even make a base of 5x5, makes it not probable.

5 times the 2x3x5 together makes 5x5x6, which is the closest I get to 5x5x5. To get that, use the following base:

> [image]

Comment: Nice diagrams, what did you use to make those?

Comment: I just googled "online 3d block builder", and this was the first site to come up :)
https://www.cbc.ca/kids/games/play/3d-block-builder